# Figma API: Accessing user's files, projects or teams

Tags: figma-api

I was trying to play with the Figma API for a side project, and I was wondering if there's any way to access the files, the projects, or the teams for a specific user (after OAuth).

I can't find any endpoint that seems to do that on the docs. [There's an endpoint](https://www.figma.com/developers/docs#get-team-projects-endpoint) that allows to retrieve all the projects for a specific team ID, the problem is that I have no idea how to get this team ID if I don't get any information on the user after the OAuth.
If anyone has any idea, that would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that feature is available yet, their documentation just covers retrieving basic information (id, handle, img_url, email) about a single user and not the files they have worked on, projects or teams they belonged to.

Answer (score 0):

I found the team ID by using Figma in the browser and just seeing what was beeing passed in the URL. For example, to get the Team ID I just took it from the long string of numbers in the this dummy URL `https://www.figma.com/files/team/555095046987901458/Team-Name`

I've had to go looking for other ones while working with the API and watching network requests in the Figma app (or browser) has been another way to values I've wanted to use.